# hiding li of a tree,using jQuery works in firefox but not in IE8

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery to show and hide li elements of a tree(tree is build using ul and li elements ) based on some condition.
here is my code.

function filterLeftNavTree(filterData){

```
    if(filterData.indexOf("|")!=-1){  

        $("ul.treeview").find("li").hide();  

        var filterData = filterData.split("|"); 

        for(i=0;i<filterData.length;i++){    
            $("ul.treeview").find("li").filter(":contains(\'"+filterData[i]+"\')").show();  
        }  
    }else{  
        $("ul.treeview").find("li").hide().filter(":contains(\'"+filterData+"\')").show();  
    }
```

}

in this function what i am doing is, passing data which can be string seperated by | .
then first hiding all li, then showing only tjose li which matched to string passed to
function.
this function is working fine in Firefox but not in IE8.  any one can please tell me why?
any alternate solution is also good for  me.
guys plz help me out.

thanks
vivek

Comment: Maybe the jQuery selector `:contains` isn't supported in IE8? Just a thought. I can't see anything _wrong_ with it.

Comment: @Fred I believe jQuery supports all popular browsers so IE8 shouldn't been excluded for this selector.

@vivek Did you see any JS error warning in IE8, or anything else weird when invoking the function?

Comment: Can you please provide some example, just tested it and it works in IE8 too, so it may depend on your markup/filterData

Comment: no,i am not getting any js error while this function is being called.

Comment: That is an extremely old version of jQuery. Can you upgrade from your current version? It will probably resolve a fair number of issues.

Comment: yes, i upgrade it with 1.4.2,but it couldn't help  me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Solved this problem.
Actually, while picking data in filterData, it picks spaces too.
and filter function is case-sensitive, so its not working in ie8.
i just trimed those spaces and its working fine in ie8.

```
if(filterData.indexOf("|")!=-1){  

        $("ul.treeview").find("li").hide();  

        var filterData = filterData.split("|"); 

        for(i=0;i<filterData.length;i++){    
            $("ul.treeview").find("li").filter(":contains(\'"+filterData[i].trim()+"\')").show();  
        }  
    }else{  
        $("ul.treeview").find("li").hide().filter(":contains(\'"+filterData.trim()+"\')").show();  
}
```

any way, thanks to all of you.
**Vivek**